# Looping through all values of a byte array

Tags: go, recursion

I'm trying to loop through all values of a small byte array (64 bytes). I want to increment the way a digital clock would, start at index 0, go 0-255 then increment index 1, repeat. I know this is probably a recursion method, but I can't wrap my head around the logic.

So basically, for a 4 byte array (smaller for convenience)

> Round 1
>
> value: [0 0 0 0]
>
> Round 256
>
> value [ 255 0 0 0]
>
> Round 256
>
> value [ 0 1 0 0 ]
>
> Round 257
>
> value [ 1 1 0 0 ]

What I have so far:

```
func allValues() {
    currentPlaceIndex := 0
    content := make([]uint8, 64)
    max := 256

    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        content[currentPlaceIndex] = uint8(i)
    }
    fmt.Println(content)
    content[currentPlaceIndex] = 0

}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to recurse this.

Comment: By my calculations, there are 256^64=2^512 possible states that this array could be in. I don't think you can realistically loop through all of these combinations before the heat death of the universe.

Comment: Better start now then! jk... it seems you have answered the question I should have been asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Converting round number to byte array

This representation is basically the base 256 radix. The first byte will be the `round number % 256`. Then divide the round number by 256, and repeat until the round number becomes 0.

Since 256 is a special number (256 = 2<sup>8</sup>), you may use bitwise operations for the calculations. E.g. the remainder is equal to bitmasking with `0xff`, and the division by 256 is equal to shifting right by 8.

Also note that there is a [`big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int) type in the standard library which represents a (signed) multi-precision integer. And it has an [`Int.Bytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Bytes) method which returns the absolute value as a big-endian byte slice. This is "almost" what we want, it's just in different byte order. So you may simply convert a round number to `big.Int` (e.g. using the [`Int.SetString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.SetString) method), get its byte slice and reverse it.

### Iterating over the values

If you don't want to convert a single round number but just iterate over the subsequent values, then do it like this:

1. You start with a full zero slice or array.
2. Check the first element of the slice. If < 255, simply increment it by one. Done with the iteration.
3. If it was 255, zero it, and attempt to do the same with the 2nd element: go to step 2.

So if you have a state, this is how you can calculate the next one:

```
func next(data []byte) {
    for idx := range data {
        if data[idx] < 255 {
            data[idx]++
            return
        }
        data[idx] = 0
    }
    fmt.Println("overflow")
}
```

This is how you can test it:

```
data := make([]byte, 64)
for iter := 0; iter < 600; iter++ {
    next(data)
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kYpaq5EpwMH)):

```
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
...
[255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
...
[255 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
...
```

Comment: That first thing you put in your answer... I thought about that. I wasn't sure if I could essentially make my own data type? an int with a base of 256?

Comment: @Jeff That is just the meaning of the representation. But this "data structure" is basically just a byte slice: `[]byte`.

Comment: I've never done the bitwise operations before. Is that the better way to go?

Comment: @Jeff The first section is if you want to convert a single, arbitrary round number to this byte slice. If you just want to generate them sequentially, then the 2nd section covers that.

Comment: @Jeff I used to avoid bitwise ops at all cost, but parsing video requires it.I hated it at first,but now I say bitwise is the best way to go. I just noticed this post is a few years old, but I already wrote everything so I am leaving it.